# Template compiling in simple Perl template system

Tags: perl, templates, eval

I need to write a simple template system with two types of macros — variable (like `<% TPL name=userName %>`) and function (like `<% TPL func=time param=now %>` or `<% TPL func=rand %>`).

It's all OK but I need to add template compilation. I want to replace variable macros with Perl variables (`<% TPL name=userName %>` to `$userName` or `$vars->{userName}`) and functions to `"Some text $rand->() blah blah"` or `"Some text $func->{time}->('now') and blah blah blah"`.

I made it for variables:

```
my $tpl = eval 'sub { my $vars = shift; "Hello, $vars-{userName}!" }';
return $tpl->({ userName => 'John' });
```

but I don't know how to do it for functions. This code doesn't work:

```
my $tpl = eval 'sub { my $func = shift; "Today is $func->{time}->('day')" }';
return $tpl->({ time => \&_time });
```

How can I get functions to work?

*P.S. I do not need another template system (TT, HTML::Template or another)*

Comment: With a number of solid templating options available in Perl, writing yet another could use further justification. The challenges you are running into are another reason to consider the existing alternatives.

Comment: If you are not using the CPAN modules you could at least take a look at how they are implemented..

Comment: Making a template system is hard; why are you trying to create your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical part is

```
"Today is $func->{time}->('day')"
```

which doesn't work, because you cannot call a function from inside a string / cannot interpolate a coderef. You can choose between the following solutions:

```
"Today is " . $func->{time}->('day');

"Today is @{[$func->{time}->('day')]}";

my $today = $func->{time}->('day');
"Today is $today";
```

Your code is sick anyway because you use an `eval` instead of just an anonymous sub, or a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)!
You could just write

```
my $tpl = sub {
   my ($vars) = @_;
   return "Hello, $vars->{userName}!";
};
return $tpl->({ userName => 'John' });
```

and

```
my $tpl = sub {
   my ($func) = @_;
   return "Today is $func->{time}->('day')";
};
return $tpl->({ time => \&_time });
```

**Hint**: When building such a templating system, the `/e` option can really help:

```
$template =~ s{<% func=(\w+) param=(\w+) %>}{join(' ',$hash->{$1}->($2))}e;
```